# Setting Up Visual Studio code to work with R - "win32 can't use R"

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, plugins

I am trying to set up R to work with Visual Studio code.
When i execute a line with the keys `CTRL`+`ENTER` I get the error "win32 can't use R".

I am following the advice laid out in this [medium post](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/a-fresh-start-for-r-in-vscode-ec61ed108cf6) where i have managed to install all the extensions but am unsure where to apply point *"4. Finally add these lines in the settings.json of your editor"*

I have seen the [this post](https://supunkavinda.blog/vscode-editing-settings-json) which describes (I think) how to update the settings.JSON but to be honest im not sure where and if this is the correct place to add the lines in the original post.

The JSON file on my PC looks like the below

```
{
    "[json]": {
    
        "editor.quickSuggestions": {
            "strings": true
        },
        "editor.suggest.insertMode": "replace",
        "gitlens.codeLens.scopes": [
            "document"
        ]
    }
}
```

Could someone point me in the right direction

Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When I had this error, I did the following with Win10Pro (20H2) and VSC 1.53.0-insider

1. Locate your R.exe location. Mine is at `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.2\bin\x64\R.exe`
2. Open VSC, once loaded, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to open your settings. In "Search Settings" type "R".
3. In the left column under "Commonly Used" scroll down to `Extensions > R`
4. In the settings for "R", scroll down to `R > Rpath: Windows`
5. Enter the RPath determined in #1 above, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save. Or when you close the "Settings" pane, I think it should save.
6. You may have to do the above with `Rterm.exe` as well.
7. Restart VSC and the error should go away.

[image]

Comment: Just came across your great answer, works fine for me! However, when I open an .R file in a fresh VSCode session and try to run a line of code, my R always starts in the terminal first, and the code is not executed until I run the line a second time. Is that normal behavior?

Comment: Or @JohnSmith , do you make similar experiences?

Comment: @JohnSmith I think that is the R>Rterm right below the largest red box in the image. Rpath is the path to the executable. I think Rterm is the R path for terminal. Maybe, for Windows, try putting "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.2\bin\x64\Rterm.exe" is that is your path to the Rterm.exe.

Comment: This solution did not solve the problem for me

Comment: Irony: When MS VScode and MS RRO do not work well together on Windows 11.

Comment: Doubling the antislash `\\\` works for me.

Comment: In other words, write `C:\\R\\R-4.1.2\\bin\\x64\\R.exe`

Comment: My R path and R term for Windows is empty, but each time I open and execute a .R file, my local R is automatically attached. How does VSCode figure out where the executable or terminal is?

Comment: @Patrick I haven't looked into this in a while, like about two years. But my first guess would be R is in your PATH/at a standard default location and/or you are not using 'vanilla' R? Or maybe you installed an extension that figures it out for you?

Comment: I can't find a way to save the settings, Ctrl+S doesn't do anything

Comment: @Julien Changes to the Settings will save automatically as soon as a change is made.

Answer (score 9):

Just to point out that @Andrew was correct with his last comment to his answer. At least on my Windows installation I had to put **both** paths in order to get rid of the *"win32 can't use R"* error, i.e. the path to R.exe shown in the screenshot plus the path to Rterm.exe at the entry `R > Rterm: Windows`. Without the second entry the error persisted in my case.

Answer (score 9):

File -> Preferences -> Settings

**Rpath:** `C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\R\R-4.2.1\bin\R.exe`

**Rterm:** `C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\R\R-4.2.1\bin\R.exe`

Then install at least one library using RGui (which is outside of VScode).

Restart VScode will then it will recognize the R library path.

Answer (score 3):

Even changing both settings in the way @Dr_Be mentions, I still couldn't run R code. This is the error I got:

> Cannot find R client at "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.2\bin\x64\Rterm.exe". Please check r.rterm setting.

The reason for these errors was that I was pasting the filepath to both R.exe and Rterm.exe (as the previous answers point out) with quotes at the beginning and ending of the filepath, as you would when using CLI. Just paste them without the quotes and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

My fix to resolve 'win32 can't use R' in VSCode was to uninstall R and install without 32-bit at all.

When installing R, there is the option to install 32-bit and 64-bit.  I de-selected 32-bit, and now it works fine.

As a noob, my first install included both 32-bit AND 64-bit (although it was installed into the 64-bit Program Files)...

Comment: sounds like a lot of work, and MS should be able to make this work without uninstalling software.