# Set up R in Visual Studio code: Path to shell executable "..." is not a file of a symlink

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I am trying to set up R to work with Visual Studio code. When I invoke a function in an R script, I get the following message: "The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources" is not a file of a symlink."

I have checked the home folder for R using R.home(), which provides "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources".

To solve this problem, I have followed the advice laid out in this [medium post](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/a-fresh-start-for-r-in-vscode-ec61ed108cf6) and followed [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65823681/setting-up-visual-studio-code-to-work-with-r-win32-cant-use-r).

Under settings I have added the following lines:

```
"r.bracketedPaste": true,
"r.rterm.mac": "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources",
"r.lsp.debug": true,
"r.rpath.mac": "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources", 
"r.lsp.diagnostics": true,
"r.rterm.option": [
"--no-save",
"--no-restore",
"--r-binary=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources"
]
```

However, this results in the same error.

Comment: Note that R.home() returns a directory, whereas those settings require executable files.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure your "r.rterm.mac" is right

Mine is

```
"r.rterm.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.0.3\\bin\\R.exe",
```

and it works

You could also take a look at [Setting Up Visual Studio code to work with R - "win32 can't use R"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65823681/setting-up-visual-studio-code-to-work-with-r-win32-cant-use-r)

Comment: I have tried several options for r.rterm.mac. Neither worked.

Comment: @msgh mmm... did you try to set path to executable (whatever it is on Mac) itself?

Comment: how would I proceed for that?

Comment: @msgh Typically on UNIX, in the terminal, `which R`, `type R` or `locate R` should do the job

Comment: Thank you @Severin Pappadeux, if I type locate R in the terminal, I get /usr/local/bin/R; if I use R.home() in RStudio, I get /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources.

Comment: @msgh One might be the link to the other. Did you try to put `/usr/local/bin/R` as string to "r.rterm.mac" and "r.rpath.mac" ?

Comment: yes, I did. I reinstalled R, looked up the location of R in the R console and got: "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources". I changed the path to: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/bin . I now get a new error message: "Cannot find R client.  Please check R path in preferences and reload." Do I need to specify anything further at the end of the path, e.g. R/exec etc?

Comment: I exhausted all my ideas, sorry. I just pretty sure it should be path to actual binary of R

Comment: @msgh You definitely need the name of the executable at the end of the path (e.g., R, R.exe).