# ! Linter 'object_length_linter' failed in : path[1]="": no such file or directory in R extension in vscode

Tags: r, vscode-extensions, linter

Background:I am trying to use R with vscode. I followed the instructions given by the official website.[here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/r).

Issue:However, it reports "Failed to run diagnostics: ! in callr subprocess. Caused by error: ! Linter 'object_length_linter' failed in : path[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcfFn.png)="": no such file or directory." when i create a new file. I didn't type anything, but it still shows the error.
When I unistall the R extension, the warning stops, and everything works just fine. I am wondering what is the problem.[my vscode page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGk8V.png)

Thanks:I searched for the error code but i don't see similar cases on google or whatsoever. I am new to programming so it might be silly (idk). Thanks for your time and guidance.

1. I tried to search for the error code.
   nothing happens. Also i can use Rstudio to edit, so i don't think it is the problem.
2. I tried to reinstall the languageserver /R language/R extension in vscode.
   It won't work.

Comment: This may be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65823681/setting-up-visual-studio-code-to-work-with-r-win32-cant-use-r